# Creating a search in Google Sheets Sidebar

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I have a sheet to track about 1400 parking spaces and was wanting to add an individual search in the sidebar. I have been able to get the sidebar to show up with a custom menu click. In the sidebar I have been able to rename it, add a search bar, and add search and close buttons below the bar.

I am now needing help with once the user enters the space number in the search bar and clicks Search it will then take that space number, look through column B and collect the following information from that row and return to the sidebar in the below format:

- Column B: 'Return Column B information'
- Column C: 'Return Column C information'
- Column D: 'Return Column D information'
- Column E: 'Return Column E information'
- Column F: 'Return Column F information'
- Column G: 'Return Column G information'
- Row number: 'Return Row number that information is in'

Below are the the codes I have right now.

Menu.gs

```
function onOpen() { 

SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
.createMenu('Sidebar')
.addItem('Show Sidebar', 'showSidebar')
.addToUi(); 
}
```

Sidebar.gs

```
function showSidebar() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Individual Space Lookup');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showSidebar(html);
}

function searchInfo() {

return ('test');    

}
```

index.html

```
<div>

Search Individual Space: <input type="search" />

<BR>

<input type="button" value="Search"
onclick="google.script.run.onSuccess()" />

<input type="button" value="Close"
onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

<script> 

function onSuccess(searchInfo) {

alert('Column B: ' + searchInfoColB
    <br>'Column C: ' + searchInfoColC
    <br>'Column D: ' + searchInfoColD
    <br>'Column E: ' + searchInfoColE
    <br>'Column F: ' + searchInfoColF
    <br>'Column G: ' + searchInfoColG
    <br>'Row Number: ' + searchInfoRowNum

    );
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
  .searchInfo(); 

</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first input tag should have an "id" attribute.  This is for retrieving the input value.

```
Search Individual Space: <input type="search" id="idUserInput"/>
```

Your Button Input Tag is configured wrong.  You have:

```
<input type="button" value="Search"
  onclick="google.script.run.onSuccess()" />
```

It should be:

```
<input type="button" value="Search"
  onclick="myFunction()" />
```

You have a SCRIPT tag with an `onSuccess` function, that then uses `google.script.run` to call the Google server function.  Right now, you are calling the server code in two places.

Your SCRIPT tag has only one function, it needs two:

```
<script>

  function onSuccess() {
    alert('Column B: ' + searchInfoColB
      <br>'Column C: ' + searchInfoColC
      <br>'Column D: ' + searchInfoColD
      <br>'Column E: ' + searchInfoColE
      <br>'Column F: ' + searchInfoColF
      <br>'Column G: ' + searchInfoColG
      <br>'Row Number: ' + searchInfoRowNum
    );
  };

  function myFunction() {
    //Get the space number out of the input field
    var theSpaceNumber = document.getElementById("idUserInput").value;

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .searchInfo(theSpaceNumber); 
  };

</script>
```

### Pass the Parking Space Number to the gs Function

```
//Get the space number out of the input field
var theSpaceNumber = document.getElementById("idUserInput").value;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
  .searchInfo(theSpaceNumber);
```

The above code is for the client side code in your SCRIPT tag.  Add the line to get the space number out of the input box, and put the `theSpaceNumber` variable into the function call.  `.searchInfo(theSpaceNumber);`

Here is an outline of how to start the server side code:

### Get a reference to the spreadsheet you want to access:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("theSpreadsheet ID");
//Logger.log(ss.getName());
```

### Get a reference to the sheet you need to access:

```
var sheetWithData = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name Here");
```

### Get the number of rows to go through:

```
var numOfRowsInSheet = sheetWithData.getLastRow();
```

So, so far you would have this:

```
function searchInfo(argSpaceNumber) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("theSpreadsheet ID");
  //Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var sheetWithData = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name Here");
  var numOfRowsInSheet = sheetWithData.getLastRow();

  return ('test');    
};
```

Now you need to determine what the best way to get the initial data is.  Are you going to get a big block of data, or go through and pick out data cell by cell?  Well, all the data you need is in contiguous columns, that makes it easier.  And you are only getting one row of data, so that makes it easier.  But the problem is, what parking space is associated with what row?  I'm going to assume that you have the parking space number in column A.  So you need to find the row number that the parking space number is in.

### Get All Data in Column A

```
var values = sheetWithData.getSheetValues(1, 1, numOfRowsInSheet, 1);
Logger.log(values);
```

### Find the Space Number in Column A

```
//Convert two dimensional array to one dimensional array.
var theRowValues = [];

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   theRowValues.push(values[i]);
};

var rowWithSpaceNumber = theRowValues.indexOf(argSpaceNumber.toString());
Logger.log("rowWithSpaceNumber: " + rowWithSpaceNumber);
```

### Get All the Values Out of the Row

```
//Get 6 columns of data:  getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)
var theRowData = sheetWithData.getSheetValues(rowWithSpaceNumber, 2, 1, 6);
```

Make these changes, test and debug the code, and if you have any errors, post another question with the error message, and/or the returned result and the expected result.

Use debug and/or `Logger.log()` statements to debug your code.

Comment: Thank you for all the updates. I have been making the changes and working on editing the code. I do have a question, you had mentioned that the input tag should be "Text" and not "Search", what is the difference between the two? Also, I am getting an error where should I post the new codes? Should I edit the original post or add an answer?

Comment: Actually, you can use the search type.  The **search** type displays an "X" in the right of the field after the user starts typing.  A text box doesn't.  Clicking that "X" will delete the current entry in the search box. That's actually nice to have.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Please post another question.  Here's why.  This question is very broad, and there are lots of issues with the code.  And the answer is very long.  In order to avoid an extended discussion in the comments, and comply more completely with stackoverflow guidelines, it's better to post a new question.  Please mark this answer as correct, then post another question.  That will also help with your points.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @Sandy Good. I have posed the new question.